# Website scraping javascript element with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I **scrape** the page with bs4 and requests python. I want to get all the values ​​given below `span`.
My code returns an empty output.

### That is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAL27GM7owB-wouEznTgEc042sYEQEVDVrvFu5gPk62z1oKnTUhzN297s6vD5rzOVWHpoex7Zc8frVJe0saldAedZOe49BauM9YtLDhHtx6PMlH4ENmihvT2fgmlnqsAPFFqfC9aW1dF_NgBYi6lfREpk6uUwP7DnDhikzgEkYIUd'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Mobile Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Fz(s) Mt(4px) Mb(0px) Fw(b) D(ib)'):
  print(i.text)
```

Comment: Does that page use javascript to create those elements?  `requests` doesn't understand javascript.

Comment: Yes it does. Then what else should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `User-Agent` to obtain the correct values:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAL27GM7owB-wouEznTgEc042sYEQEVDVrvFu5gPk62z1oKnTUhzN297s6vD5rzOVWHpoex7Zc8frVJe0saldAedZOe49BauM9YtLDhHtx6PMlH4ENmihvT2fgmlnqsAPFFqfC9aW1dF_NgBYi6lfREpk6uUwP7DnDhikzgEkYIUd"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all(
    "span", class_="Trsdu(0.3s) Fz(s) Mt(4px) Mb(0px) Fw(b) D(ib)"
):
    print(i.text)
```

Prints:

```
4,181.17
33,874.85
13,962.68
```

Comment: Now it works but why only shows 3 results as there are so many more spans about this class?

Comment: @Michaelwgg The page uses Javascript heavily. Better to use Yahoo API (if they have one), or `selenium`. BeautifulSoup doesn't execute javascript.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without opening a browser and doing it in the "background"?

Comment: @Michaelwgg Yes, `selenium` can be used "headless". You can also open Firefox (Chrome) Developer Tools -> Network Tab and watch where the page is doing requests. Many pages are using Json/XML requests to load their data and you can simulate it.